# data aggregation with sum pandas/ python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, analytics

```py
import pandas as pd
dane= pd.read_csv('WHO-COVID-19-global-data _2.csv')
dane

dane.groupby('Country')[['Cumulative_cases']].sum()
```

KeyError: 'Country'

I don't know why this code doesn't run?

Comment: Please provide some sample data of dane dataframe

Comment: https://covid19.who.int/table

Comment: External links can become invalid, better show it as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Date_reported, Country_code, Country, WHO_region, New_cases, Cumulative_cases, New_deaths, Cumulative_deaths
2020-01-03,AF,Afghanistan,EMRO,0,0,0,0
2020-01-04,AF,Afghanistan,EMRO,0,0,0,0
2020-01-05,AF,Afghanistan,EMRO,0,0,0,0

Answer (score 2):

There are spaces at the beginning of dane columns

Remove them with the following line:

```
dane.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)    
dane.groupby('Country')[['Cumulative_cases']].sum()

                                             

    Cumulative_cases
 Country
Afghanistan                                                   5702767
Albania                                                       1300156
Algeria                                                       5561691
American Samoa                                                      0
Andorra                                                        273756
...                                                               ...
Wallis and Futuna                                                  14
Yemen                                                          256353
Zambia                                                        1323403
Zimbabwe                                                       692447
occupied Palestinian territory, including east ...            4057017
```

Comment: it runs, many thanks, how to avoid this problem? is there any function to delete spaces before names of variable? or should I make it manually in Excel for instance?

Comment: I adde one more line at the beginning that removes the spaces